# How force the app to opt out of battery saver mode when the service is ON?

Tags: java, android, xiaomi, battery-saver

The expected behavior is that the app will be running all the time when it's in ON state. Some phones put the app in background mode when the app is not active for some time. I want the app to be running all the time even its in standby mode(standby mode means when we press the home button the app will go to background. and it will run for some time).

I found following code and I tried that

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    String packageName = "org.traccar.client";
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }
```

Even after working with the code the default state is Battery Saver(recommended) 
[image]

I want the app in No Restriction mode once the app is opened, any solution for this?

Comment: your app can't change system settings, as well as you can't decide how the user wants your app to work. If you want your app to run *always* after it has been started - use foreground service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use is for **battery optimization**. Settings-->Batery-->Three Dots Menu Item (...)--->Battery Optimization-->(Choose an app from list)--->Optimize/ Don't optimize.

By choosing `Don't optimize` you are essentially bypassing `Doze`, not `app standby`.

Also be advised that doing this programmatically as you do **may result in Google taking your app off the store**. It is safer to do it **manually** following the path i described above.

More on `Doze` and App `Standby`  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)

Comment: i am not uploading it to app store. but i want to achieve this